# Simulator Launch issue in xcode 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

When I open xcode 5 and run any project it gives "SpringBoard Failed to launch application with error: -3".

[image]

Plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reset simulator
2. Clean dependencies
3. Clean derived data
4. you are all set to go

worst case
Restart Machine.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your `iOSSimulator` & launch it again by running any project on `Xcode`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reset Simulator
2. Quit Simulator (cmd + Q)
3. Run again (cmd + R)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, I found that deleting my app from the simulator also solved the issue.